# How can I display a byte array in my database as an image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Here is my action that leads to a view, in which you upload a file. The file then is stored in my database as a byte array.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(ImageViewModel model)
        {
            byte[] data = null;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await model.Data.CopyToAsync(ms);
                data = ms.ToArray();
            }

            var picture = new Picture()
            {
                Name = model.Name,
                Image = data
            };

            await context.Images.AddAsync(picture);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Here is my upload page view:

```
@model ImageViewModel

<form asp-controller="Image" asp-action="Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <div class ="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Data" class="control-label"></label>
        <input type="file" asp-for="@Model.Data" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload!" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

My question is what are the ways I can display the image on a view in my MVC project?

Do I need to convert it to a IFormFile or is there another way like converting it to a base64 string?

Comment: This article appears to cover all of the details for what you want to do: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/mvc-display-image-from-byte-array/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is what are the ways I can display the image on a view in
> my MVC project?

You can use the following code to display the byte array as image in the view:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image)" />
```

**Note:** But if your images' format are all different, you need add an extra property to store the format. You could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73469111/11398810). The second option in this answer would help you.

---

A simple working demo you could follow:

Model

```
public class ImageViewModel
{
    public IFormFile Data { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

View(Index)

```
@model IEnumerable<Picture>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image)
            </th>
           
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image)" />

                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await context.Images.ToListAsync());
}
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(ImageViewModel model)
{
    byte[] data = null;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await model.Data.CopyToAsync(ms);
        data = ms.ToArray();
    }

    var picture = new Picture()
    {
        Name = model.Name,
        Image = data
    };

    await context.Images.AddAsync(picture);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two most common options:

1- You can read the byte array from database and convert it to base64 and set it as

2- You can create an new action (e.g. file) which has "id" parameter, as below:

```
public async Task<FileContentResult> File(int id){
    // SELECT imageByteArray, contentType from [Images] WHERE Id = id

    // return File(imageByteArray, contentType)  // Add fileDownloadName parameter to force the browser to download 
}
```

My recommendation would be the later one, because it is more flexible and  practical than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

you can save image on a direct path in your server and In order not to have the same name generate a Guid name for image

```
  string image = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") + Path.GetExtension(formFile.FileName); 
  string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/img", image);
  using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
  {   
      await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
  }
```

you should save image Guid in database and show image in view like this

```
<img src="~/wwwroot/img/@item.ImageGuid"/>
```